# Xcode 4.5: NSLayoutConstraint issue in iphone 5.1 simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, crash

**I am getting an error**:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason:`

```
'Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint'
```

when I am trying to run my application in **iPhone 5.1 simulator**. It works fine on my iOS 6.0 and 5.0 Simulator and on my device too. It crashed before it runs the app, actually it crashes on the splash screen. Trying to delete the app doesn't work. It cant be deleted from the device, so I deleted it from */User/"name"/library/application support/simulator/my app*. If I touch the X in the simulator it freezes. "`Autolayout`" is **unchecked**, otherwise it would not run at all. 
Do have anyone suggestions what to do now?

Comment: iOS 5 doesn't support autolayout. If you want to target a version of iOS prior to iOS 6, you can't use autolayout in your storyboards/nibs.

Comment: autolayout is not beeing used anyway!

Comment: Have you tried reseting the simulator using the menu option `iOS Simulator`->`Reset Content and Settings...`?

Comment: yes also that I tried but it doesn't work on iOS. 5.1 Simulator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Storyboards, you need to select the main Storyboard, right-click and select `Show File Inspector`. In the File Inspector pane, under `File Versioning > Document Versioning`, select iOS 5.x for Deployment and uncheck `Use Autolayout`.

Answer (score 5):

Just disable autoLayout from FileInspector - InterfaceBuilderDocument and it will work on iOS 5 too.